# ASP.NET Core : an error occurred while exporting Mandate with Schedules reports to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In ASP.NET Core Web API, I have an application that queries, search filter and export to Excel using EPPlus. I am generating an Excel report with sub-report.

I got this error:

> [ERR] An error occurred while exporting Mandate with Schedules reports to Excel.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
>
> at Services.Concrete.Admin.AdminMandatesService.ExportMandateWithDetailListToExcelAsync(PagingFilter filter) in
> C:\Services\Concrete\Admin\AdminMandatesService.cs:line 0

The query uses a row limiting operator (`Skip/Take`) without an `OrderBy` operator.

This may lead to unpredictable results. If the `Distinct` operator is used after `OrderBy`, then make sure to use the `OrderBy` operator

Kindly help resolve with complete code

Main code - repository:

`GetMandateWithDetailListAsync`:

```
public IQueryable<Mandate> GetMandateWithDetailListAsync(PagingFilter filter)
{
    try
    {
        IQueryable<Mandate> query = _dbContext.Mandates
                    .Include(x => x.MandateDetails)
                    .Include(x => x.MandateApproval)
                    .Include(x => x.Merchant)
                    .Include(x => x.BankBranch);

        // Apply search filtering
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SearchQuery))
        {
            query = query
                .Where(m =>
                m.Merchant.MerchantName.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery) ||
                m.ReferenceNumber.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery) ||
                m.DrAccountNumber.Contains(filter.SearchQuery) ||
                (m.PaymentFrequency == PaymentFrequency.Monthly ? "monthly"
                  : m.PaymentFrequency == PaymentFrequency.Quarterly ? "quarterly"
                  : m.PaymentFrequency == PaymentFrequency.BiAnnual ? "biannual"
                  : m.PaymentFrequency == PaymentFrequency.Yearly ? "yearly"
                  : "unknown"
                  ).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower()) ||
                m.BankBranch.BranchName.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery) ||
                m.Amount.ToString().Contains(filter.SearchQuery) ||
                (m.MandateApprovalStatus == MandateApprovalStatus.PendingApproval ? "pending approval"
                  : m.MandateApprovalStatus == MandateApprovalStatus.Declined ? "declined"
                  : m.MandateApprovalStatus == MandateApprovalStatus.Approved ? "approved"
                  : "unknown"
                  ).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
                );
        }

        // Apply date range filtering
        if (filter.StartDate.HasValue && filter.EndDate.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(m => m.CreatedAt >= filter.StartDate.Value && m.CreatedAt <= filter.EndDate.Value);
        }

        // Apply sorting
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SortBy))
        {
            switch (filter.SortBy)
            {
                case "MerchantName":
                    query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.Merchant.MerchantName) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.Merchant.MerchantName);
                    break;
                case "ReferenceNumber":
                    query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.ReferenceNumber) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.ReferenceNumber);
                    break;
                case "DrAccountNumber":
                    query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.DrAccountNumber) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.DrAccountNumber);
                    break;
                case "BranchName":
                    query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.BankBranch.BranchName) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.BankBranch.BranchName);
                    break;
                case "Amount":
                    query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.Amount) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.Amount);
                    break;
                case "MandateApprovalStatus":
                    query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.MandateApprovalStatus) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.MandateApprovalStatus);
                    break;
                case "CreatedAt":
                    query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.CreatedAt) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedAt);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            query = query.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedAt);
        }

        return query;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("An error occurred while retrieving Mandate with Details.", ex);
    }
}
```

Service - `GetMandateWithDetailListAsync`:

```
public async Task<Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<AdminMandateListDto>>>> GetMandateWithDetailListAsync(PagingFilter filter)
{
    try
    {
        var query = _unitOfWork.AdminMandates.GetMandateWithDetailListAsync(filter);

        var totalRecords = await query.CountAsync();
        var item = await query.PaginationAsync<Mandate, AdminMandateListDto>(filter.PageNumber, filter.PageSize, _mapper);

        var pageResult = new PageResult<IEnumerable<AdminMandateListDto>>
        {
            PageItems = item.PageItems,  // Update this line
            CurrentPage = filter.PageNumber,
            PageSize = filter.PageSize,
            NumberOfPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalRecords / filter.PageSize),
            TotalRecord = totalRecords
        };

        return new Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<AdminMandateListDto>>>()
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Successful = true,
            Data = pageResult,
            Message = "All Mandate with Schedules Retrieved Successfully"
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex, "An error occurred while retrieving Mandate with Schedules reports.");
        return new Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<AdminMandateListDto>>>()
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            Successful = false,
            Message = "An error occurred while retrieving Mandate with Schedules reports."
        };
    }
}
```

`ExportMandateWithDetailListToExcelAsync`:

```
public async Task<Response<byte[]>> ExportMandateWithDetailListToExcelAsync(PagingFilter filter)
{
    try
    {
        var auditReportsResponse = await GetMandateWithDetailListAsync(filter);
        var auditReports = auditReportsResponse.Data.PageItems; // Retrieve the PageItems property from the auditReportsResponse object

        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
        var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage();
        var worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Mandate with Schedules Reports");

        // Title
        var title = "Mandate with Schedules Reports";
        var titleCell = worksheet.Cells["A1:K1"]; // Adjust the range based on the number of columns
        titleCell.Merge = true;
        titleCell.Value = title;
        titleCell.Style.Font.Size = 16;
        titleCell.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        titleCell.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
        titleCell.Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;
        titleCell.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        titleCell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);

        // Headers
        var headers = new List<string>
        {
            "S.No.",
            "Merchant Name",
            "Reference Number",
            "Customer Account No.",
            "Branch",
            "Payment Frequency",
            "Start Date",
            "End Date",
            "Amount",
            "Approval Status",
            "Action Date"
        };

        // Set header values
        for (int i = 0; i < headers.Count; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[2, i + 1].Value = headers[i];
            worksheet.Cells[2, i + 1].Style.Font.Bold = true;
            worksheet.Cells[2, i + 1].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            worksheet.Cells[2, i + 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);
        }

        // Populate data rows
        var row = 3;
        var serialNumber = 1;

        foreach (var report in auditReports)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = serialNumber;
            worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value = report.Merchant.MerchantName;
            worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value = report.ReferenceNumber;
            worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value = report.DrAccountNumber;
            worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Value = report.BankBranch.BranchName;
            worksheet.Cells[row, 6].Value = report.PaymentFrequency;
            worksheet.Cells[row, 7].Value = report.StartDate.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            worksheet.Cells[row, 8].Value = report.EndDate.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            worksheet.Cells[row, 9].Value = report.Amount.ToString("N2");
            worksheet.Cells[row, 10].Value = report.MandateApprovalStatus;
            worksheet.Cells[row, 11].Value = report.CreatedAt?.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") ?? string.Empty;

            // Create the collapsible group for Mandate Schedules
            var usersGroupStartRow = row + 1;
            var usersGroupEndRow = usersGroupStartRow + report.MandateDetails.Count;

            // Add group header
            worksheet.Cells[usersGroupStartRow, 1].Value = "Mandate Schedules";
            worksheet.Cells[usersGroupStartRow, 1, usersGroupStartRow, 11].Merge = true; // Adjust the range based on the number of columns
            worksheet.Cells[usersGroupStartRow, 1].Style.Font.Bold = true;
            worksheet.Cells[usersGroupStartRow, 1].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            worksheet.Cells[usersGroupStartRow, 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);

            // Populate headers for Mandate Schedules
            var userHeaderRow = usersGroupStartRow + 1;
            var userHeaders = new List<string>
            {
                "Payment Reference",
                "Due Date",
                "Narration",
                "Payment Status",
                "Payable Amount",
                "Processed Date"
            };
            worksheet.Cells[userHeaderRow, 2].LoadFromCollection(userHeaders);

            // Set the styles for the user header row
            worksheet.Row(userHeaderRow).Style.Font.Bold = true;
            worksheet.Row(userHeaderRow).Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            worksheet.Row(userHeaderRow).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);

            // Populate data for Merchant Users
            var userDataStartRow = userHeaderRow + 1;
            var userSerialNumber = 1;

            foreach (var user in report.MandateDetails)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[userDataStartRow, 2].Value = user.PaymentReference;
                worksheet.Cells[userDataStartRow, 3].Value = user.DueDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") ?? string.Empty;
                worksheet.Cells[userDataStartRow, 4].Value = user.Narration;
                worksheet.Cells[userDataStartRow, 5].Value = user.PaymentStatus;
                worksheet.Cells[userDataStartRow, 6].Value = user.PayableAmount.Value.ToString("N2") ?? string.Empty;
                worksheet.Cells[userDataStartRow, 7].Value = user.ProcessedDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") ?? string.Empty;

                userDataStartRow++;
                userSerialNumber++;
            }

            // Hide rows for Merchant Users
            worksheet.Row(usersGroupStartRow).Hidden = true;

            for (int i = usersGroupStartRow + 1; i <= usersGroupEndRow; i++)
            {
                worksheet.Row(i).Hidden = true;
            }

            row = usersGroupEndRow + 1;
            serialNumber++;
        }

        // Auto-fit columns
        worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

        var excelBytes = excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();

        return new Response<byte[]>()
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Successful = true,
            Data = excelBytes,
            Message = "Mandate with Schedules reports exported to Excel successfully."
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex, "An error occurred while exporting Mandate with Schedules reports to Excel.");
        return new Response<byte[]>()
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            Successful = false,
            Message = "An error occurred while exporting Mandate with Schedules reports to Excel."
        };
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route(ApiRoutes.Admin.GetAllMandatesWithDetails)]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetMandateWithDetailListAsync([FromQuery] PagingFilter filter, [FromQuery] bool exportToExcel = false)
{
    if (exportToExcel)
    {
        var response = await _adminMandatesService.ExportMandateWithDetailListToExcelAsync(filter);

        if (response.Successful)
        {
            var fileBytes = response.Data;
            var fileName = $"MandateWithSchedulesReports_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.xlsx";

            return File(fileBytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            return StatusCode(response.StatusCode, response.Message);
        }
    }

    var result = await _adminMandatesService.GetMandateWithDetailListAsync(filter);

    return StatusCode(result.StatusCode, result);
}
```

Comment: you need check with debug line by line and see stack trace to find which line get the null error maybe you mistake in ` worksheet.Row(i)` (Row count) remember there index start from 0 and end one index  (count-1)

Comment: Would be great if you can provide info in which line get the exception.